# SSIS script task runs locally in visual Studio but not whe deployed to a server

Tags: ssis

I've put together a quick proof of concept SSIS package to use SSIS logging within a script task using the following code in the man method

```
bool fireAgain = true;
Dts.Events.FireInformation(-1,"logging stuff", "more info  = " + Dts.Variables["User::myVar"].Value.ToString(), string.Empty, -1, ref fireAgain);
```

I have then selected all events to be logged for a text logging set up.

Locally in Visual Studio, the package does what I would expect in that the Dts.Events.FireInformation details get written to the log file.

However when deployed to the server it does not.

The pre and post validation events get logged but the code in the script appears to get bypassed completely.

I even put a throw in the code to force it to kick of but nothing happened.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and deploying to SQL Server 2016 on Windows Server 2019.

I'm thinking this must be some sort of compatibility issue but there are no errors being logged as far as I can see.

So frustrating.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Could be some of the .NET components for C# are not installed on the server that you have locally.